# String converting to Char and then to Int

Tags: java, string, casting, type-conversion, character

I'm writing a palindrome function for school which will take a string argument and remove all punctuation. For the purpose of my class, I have to use the substring() method.

My code basically takes a substring of each character in the string argument and converts it to char, and then to int. Then, it checks if that integer is within the ASCII numbers for a-z or A-Z and if it is, that substring is appended to a blank string (s2).

My main issue now is that when I try to compile the program, I get an error saying that the substring can't be converted to char. Any ideas on why?

```
  public Palindrome(String s)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
        {
//                                      checks if the character is an uppercase letter
            if((int) Character.valueOf(s.substring(i, i + 1)) >= 65)
                if((int) Character.valueOf(s.substring(i, i + 1)) <= 90)
                    s2 += s.substring(i, i+1);
//                                      checks if the character is a lowercase letter
            if((int) Character.valueOf(s.substring(i, i + 1)) >= 97)
                if((int) Character.valueOf(s.substring(i, i + 1)) <= 122)
                    s2 += s.substring(i, i+1);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `String` object *is not* a `Character` or `char`, even if the length of the `String` is one. Casting is just trying to fool the compiler, it does not change the actual underlying object.

If `String#charAt()` is forbidden, then you can use `String#toCharArray()` that will return a `char[]` (of length 1 in your case). e.g.

```
char[] myChar = s.substring(i, i + 1);
// myChar[0] contains the character
```

Then to test if it's a letter, you can use

```
Character.isLetter(myChar[0]);
```

Beware that when you cast

```
(int)Character.valueOf(...)
```

A `Character` object as returned by `valueOf()`, is not a `char`. It will actually work, because the compiler will do some *unboxing* of `Character` to `char`.

If you want to use the ASCII code instead of `Character#isLetter()`, you can do:

```
char[] myChar = s.substring(i, i + 1);
int theCharAsInt = (int)myChar[0];
// proceed to test the range
```

Because a native `char` value can be read as a native `int` value.

```
int codeA = (int)'A';  // codeA == 65
```

Answer (score 0):

[Character#valueOf(char c)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#valueOf%28char%29) method applies on character and 
As [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29) Says substring ()

```
public String substring()
```

method returns String , So you can not use `Character#valueOf` method in here